# TabControl - databinding TabItem order

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, tabcontrol

I've got a datababound TabControl and would like to bind the index of each TabItem to a corresponding property in my view model.  The ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection, and I'm using [Bea Stollnitz's Drag/Drop functionality](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53) to provide tab control re-ordering.

My gut feeling is that it should be able to be handled in the data template for the tab item header, but I haven't been able to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TabControl.ItemsSource` should be bound to your collection, so to re-arrange the order of tab items, simply re-arrange the collection.

I've worked with Bea's drag/drop code before to create a TabControl that allowed users to drag/drop the tab items, and I think most of what was needed is in the code she provides. On drop, it removes the dragged object from it's parent collection, and inserts it to its new location in the drop target collection, which in your case is the same collection.

**Edit**

Based on your comment below about updating your `ViewModel` with the Tab Index, try using the `CollectionChanged` event.

```
void MyCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in MyCollection)
        item.TabIndex = MyCollection.IndexOf(item);
}
```

Comment: Yep, I have that portion of it working, and it re-orders the tabs correctly, but I don't have any way of updating the view model of the tab that was just moved with the new index.  In other words, the TabControl.ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection<MyItem>.  In the MyItem class, I have a TabSequence property.  When I re-order a tab, I need the TabSequence property to be updated with the new tab index.

Comment: @ZF You should be able to hook into the `CollectionChanged` event and update the `TabSequence` of each item. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Perfect, I hadn't even considered the CollectionChanged event.  Thank you!